# PHP server side timeout check

Tags: php, datetime, timeout

Is there a simple straight forward way to find the remaining time between a start date - ex: `2013-01-10 12:34:55` and 5 minutes later?

What I mean is I have the start date and want to check that 5 or 60 minutes later gives a time difference of 0. Kind of a time out to be checked on server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 dates, correct ?

```
$date1 = strtotime('2013-01-10 12:34:33'); // converto to time
$date2 = strtotime('2013-01-10 12:45:33'); // or else it won't work
$diff = date('u', $date1) - date('u', $date2); // the difference in seconds between the two
// if you want $date2 to be now, just use date('u')
if ($diff > 3600) { // an hour later
    echo 'The difference between $date1 and $date2 is more than an hour';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Your solution works only with a couple of changes, but that's the what I was looking for. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something like "session time out" for the user. Use Javascript setintervel() and do ajax() call to logout user from the application.

Comment: Hi Suresh, I'm already using jQuery and session to perform the client side validation on this but as a fail safe, it's always advisable to make a "hard" verification on server side before any data can be stored in the database. I like to think that all the filters are not enough to ensure the most reliable and update data is stored. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems like I was going the harder way... found that it would be easier and more reliable to get it from an sql check than in php.
I've implemented this with success. Leave it here just in case it might be useful.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM db_table 
WHERE DATE_ADD(my_start_date, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) > NOW()";
```

Where 5 is the interval that can be set in seconds (SECOND), minutes (MINUTE), hours (HOUR), days (DAY) etc.